# Which date in 1999 was "Action Half-Life" first released?

Tags: mods, half-life

I remember briefly playing a Half-Life mod called "Action Half-Life" in 1999 in one of the few LAN "parties" I ever attended.

I have fuzzy brain pictures of a night-time city environment drenched in blue lighting, a garage, and sniper rifles.

I have made numerous searches such as `"Action Half-Life" original release date`, but search engines seem to have dropped the entire concept of returning search results that have anything to do with the search query, so I find nothing of value. The closest thing I find is the year "1999", but nothing more accurate than that.

All videos I find on YouTube of the mod/game ring no bells whatsoever. It looks nothing like I remember it from my memory. (No, I'm not confusing it with "Action Quake 2"!)

Can you help me find the exact date when this mod was first published?

Comment: [This mod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Half-Life)?

Comment: @Joachim Yes. That is the one.

Answer (score 2):

The first capture of the then official Action Half Life/AHL website (*ahl.action-web.net* - later on *ahl.telefragged.com* [that logo looks familiar :)]) that can be found on the [WayBackMachine](https://web.archive.org/) is from the 10th of October 1999 ([here](https://web.archive.org/web/19991010222710/https://ahl.action-web.net/)), and the first entry on that page is from the 17th of February that year, which talks about the Beta 3 version:

> [...] "on to the news: There is no news. Beta 3 will be comming 'REAL SOON NOW' aka 'WHEN IT'S DONE'. I really couldn't say more than that. It's pretty stable at this point. Some annoying bugs here and there."
> [...] "You will see AHL beta 3 soon. And eventually v1.0 as well."

(The ['Pre-August News' link](https://web.archive.org/web/20000818061941fw_/http://ahl.action-web.net/pre_august_news.shtml) at the bottom of the page *seems* to lead to earlier entries, but the WayBackMachine's earliest snapshot of that link is from 2002.)

Although February 17th 1999 is the earliest date I can find that shows activity on the mod, the mod likely already started being developed in late 1998, directly after the release of Half-Life.

The first publicly available release, however, seems to have been on the **16th of March**:

> "Hey Action fans. Tonights treat will certainly make you spasm. hehe
>
> The time has finally arrived, I bring you:
> Action Half-Life!
> Yes, Tonight at 8 pm EST (for europeans: thursday morning 1am GMT) I will start the release party on chat.planetquake.com channel #actionhalflife. At that time I will release the last trailer, and an hour later, you will have Beta 3!
>
> Let the games begin!"

Although this is again about the Beta 3 version, I presume this is considered to have been the official release of the mod.

---

A couple more useful (?) links:

- The team behind AHL's [Director's Cut](https://www.moddb.com/mods/ahl-directors-cut):
  https://ministryofaction.net/
- An overview of the original mod:
  https://web.archive.org/web/20110811061356fw_/http://ahl.telefragged.com/manual/index.html